# Joining tables with multiple foreign keys

Tags: sql, inner-join

Considering the following SQL query, I get no results returned. If I remove one of the `INNER JOIN`s, then it returns the data associated to the foreign key.

Notice `DefinitionID` and `TermID` are both related to the Primary Key `def.ID` of the PolicyData table.

```
SELECT def.* FROM [Questions].[dbo].[PolicyDefinitions] def
INNER JOIN [Questions].[dbo].[PolicyData] p 
ON def.ID = p.TermID
INNER JOIN [Questions].[dbo].[PolicyData] pd 
ON def.ID = pd.DefinitionID
```

Is it possible to join the tables like this?

Comment: yes, it's possible. but you're doing an inner join. if EITHER of the join conditions fail, you get nothing, because an inner join requires there be matching records on BOTH sides of the query. you probably want a `left` or `right` join instead.

Comment: Hmm, I'm wondering why inner would fail, but I just tried left and it worked perfectly. If you'd post that as an answer I'll accept it soon.

Comment: Here's a great link about [INNER AND OUTER JOINS](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Your query will only work if TermID = DefinitionId. This is what you intended ?

Comment: @DumitrescuBogdan was not what I intended lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually wanting to use a `LEFT JOIN` as data will only be returned with your query (using `INNER JOIN`) when all the joined tables have matching rows, a quick google (other search engines are available;-) ) will link you to many articles on this.

```
SELECT 
    def.* 
FROM 
    [Questions].[dbo].[PolicyDefinitions] def
    LEFT JOIN [Questions].[dbo].[PolicyData] p ON def.ID = p.TermID
    LEFT JOIN [Questions].[dbo].[PolicyData] pd ON def.ID = pd.DefinitionID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with just 1 join with an OR

```
SELECT 
    def.* 
FROM 
    [Questions].[dbo].[PolicyDefinitions] def
    JOIN [Questions].[dbo].[PolicyData] p ON def.ID = p.TermID OR def.ID = pd.DefinitionID
```